# Use ffmpeg convert mp4 video resolution ,but changed video stream format?

Tags: ffmpeg

I want to convert mp4 video resolution using FFmPEG, I use the following command:

```
ffmpeg.exe  -i '.\(G)I-DLE - Uh-Oh.mp4' -vf scale=1920:1080  1080p.mp4
```

The video stream of the input file is H264 bit stream, while the output file is mPEG4 bit stream.How to solve this problem? Here is the command line output:

```
    ffmpeg version N-104710-g12f8293c02 Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.00.24245 for x86
  configuration: --prefix=./out --extra-cflags=-I../common --toolchain=msvc --target-os=win32 --arch=x86 --enable-asm --enable-yasm --enable-gpl --disable-shared --disable-doc --disable-podpages --disable-txtpages --enable-static
  libavutil      57.  9.101 / 57.  9.101
  libavcodec     59. 14.100 / 59. 14.100
  libavformat    59.  9.102 / 59.  9.102
  libavdevice    59.  0.101 / 59.  0.101
  libavfilter     8. 17.100 /  8. 17.100
  libswscale      6.  1.101 /  6.  1.101
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '.\(G)I-DLE - Uh-Oh.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    artist          : (G)I-DLE
    comment         : 163 key(Don't modify):reZGxbjnM7jVHKNhHTowoqD/KBkrenVYXoIu24rU95dHecNWoUdka1gVaCz12onEbysjwXZQbsMRKCBZBOHaVoB9rPs/bExUC78XiecFLTSw20rpKAp6mock+Or4r3oiKYA6eT4wmbRNV/aJZNGiPLhQje+VCg4t7ASt57Pjmm4yJ1Ug0M2wvjkKx+IvqEFRP2FUmmGdOavdm/pFzXbqql/xKDgTnVSeG44a26U1z
    title           : Uh-Oh
    encoder         : Lavf57.71.100
  Duration: 00:03:30.84, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 6224 kb/s
  Stream #0:0[0x1](eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 6087 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
  Stream #0:1[0x2](eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
File '1080p.mp4' already exists. Overwrite? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> mpeg4 (native))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mpeg4 @ 04466E40] Invalid pixel aspect ratio 256/81, limit is 255/255 reducing
Output #0, mp4, to '1080p.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    artist          : (G)I-DLE
    comment         : 163 key(Don't modify):reZGxbjnM7jVHKNhHTowoqD/KBkrenVYXoIu24rU95dHecNWoUdka1gVaCz12onEbysjwXZQbsMRKCBZBOHaVoB9rPs/bExUC78XiecFLTSw20rpKAp6mock+Or4r3oiKYA6eT4wmbRNV/aJZNGiPLhQje+VCg4t7ASt57Pjmm4yJ1Ug0M2wvjkKx+IvqEFRP2FUmmGdOavdm/pFzXbqql/xKDgTnVSeG44a26U1z
    title           : Uh-Oh
    encoder         : Lavf59.9.102
  Stream #0:0(eng): Video: mpeg4 (mp4v / 0x7634706D), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 1080x1920 [SAR 177:56 DAR 1593:896], q=2-31, 200 kb/s, SAR 256:81 DAR 16:9, 25 fps, 12800 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.14.100 mpeg4
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/200000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
      vendor_id       : [0][0][0][0]
      encoder         : Lavc59.14.100 aac
frame= 5271 fps=237 q=31.0 Lsize=   76329kB time=00:03:30.80 bitrate=2966.2kbits/s speed=9.48x
video:72842kB audio:3352kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.177660%
[aac @ 04770BC0] Qavg: 969.899**strong text**
```

As you can see above, the input format is H264 and the output format is MPEG4. How can change the video resolution without changing the video stream format?

Comment: Use: `ffmpeg.exe -i '.\(G)I-DLE - Uh-Oh.mp4' -vf scale=1920:1080,setsar=1:1 -c:v libx264 1080p.mp4`. In case it's not working, update your version of FFmpeg (command line tool) - the version looks strange.

Comment: Yes，you are right. My version of ffmpeg is uncorrect. There is no libx264 encoder in this ffmpeg.Thx very much!!!